# Different output (Beginner exercise in Python 2.6)

Tags: python

I'm trying to recreate a piece of code that I've found on [Non-Programmer's Tutorial for Python 2.6](https://www.google.com.ar/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=non%20programmers%20tutorial%20python%202.6)-(Page 29):

```
n = input("Number?")
if n < 0:
    print "The absolute value of", n, "is", -n
else:
    print "The absolute value of", n, "is", n
```

But the output is different than I spected. If I put as input "-5" I received as output "-5", not "5".I don't know exactly what is the problem with that. This is my piece of code: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_ULW5rdd4VSQXxss.py

Comment: Not sure this should have been marked as a duplicate. A beginner wouldn't be aware that comparing a string and an integer in 2.x would result in odd behavior, not an error. Joac wasn't aware that input() was returning a string, which would be a pre-requisite for checking how to have input() return an integer. /me shrugs. Doesn't matter at this point, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` returns a string. What you're checking is `"-5" < 0`, which is `False`.

Change your input statement to:

```
n = int(input("Number?"))
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: Yes! You're rigth!! thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help. I'd appreciate it if you could accept the answer.